# How do I delete special character (+) except for those in between strings?

Tags: python, special-characters

I want to delete '+' in my data based on the some rules.

Let's say my data looks like below

```
++
+coke
coke+burger+
+
coke+burger+fries
coke+burger+fries+
```

Here, I want my final processed data looks like below so that all '+'s are deleted when they are not between the strings.

```
coke
coke+burger
coke+burger+fries
coke+burger+fries
```

Thanks.

I tried deleting special characters, but it deleted all the '+'s.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please consider adding a code snippet to show your progress and/or error you're facing?

Answer (score 5):

use `strip`. It returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.

```py
test = "+te+st+"
print(test.strip("+"))
```

For more information, read:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip